# Entity Framework 6.4 sets properties to null when HasChanges is called

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have an entity which includes a CreatedByUserID Property as a nullable integer which then links to the Users table and a  CreatedByUser Property in the entity points to that User.  When I initialize the CreatedByUserID (or CreatedByUser reference) and then add the object to the Payments DbSet the values are set correctly.  However, if I touch the change tracker or check if it HasChanges, just this property and the related reference gets set to null. I converted the CreatedByUserID property to a get/set pair and put a break point there.  This confirmed that Entity Framework was calling a set properties or reset properties from the stack trace below.  The bottom two entries are my code as is line at the top.  You can see it calls track changes and this nulls the parameter CreatedByUserID.  I have tried setting the CreatedByUser reference as well as the ID but neither makes a difference.

Why does detect changes need to change the values in my entity?  Should it not just be looking at the changes?  How do I get it to stop this behaviour?

> DataModels.dll!Armada.DataModels.Payment.set_CreatedByUserID(Integer? value) Line 68    Basic
>       [Lightweight Function]
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DelegateFactory.SetValue(System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmProperty property, object target, object value) + 0x3c bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.StateManagerMemberMetadata.SetValue(object userObject, object value) + 0xa0 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.SnapshotChangeTrackingStrategy.SetCurrentValue(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry entry, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.StateManagerMemberMetadata member, int ordinal, object target, object value) + 0x7c bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapper.SetCurrentValue(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry entry, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.StateManagerMemberMetadata member, int ordinal, object target, object value) + 0x40 bytes 
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.NullAllForeignKeys() + 0x5fd bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.RemoveFromLocalCache(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool resetIsLoaded, bool preserveForeignKey) + 0x8e bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.RemoveFromCache(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool resetIsLoaded, bool preserveForeignKey) + 0x32 bytes 
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Remove(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool doFixup, bool deleteEntity, bool deleteOwner, bool applyReferentialConstraints, bool preserveForeignKey) + 0x170 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.FixupOtherEndOfRelationshipForRemove(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool preserveForeignKey) + 0x53 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Remove(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool doFixup, bool deleteEntity, bool deleteOwner, bool applyReferentialConstraints, bool preserveForeignKey) + 0x218 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Remove(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool doFixup, bool deleteEntity, bool deleteOwner, bool applyReferentialConstraints, bool preserveForeignKey) + 0x153 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Remove(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, bool preserveForeignKey) + 0x64 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.PerformDelete(System.Collections.Generic.IList entries) + 0x99f bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AlignChangesInRelationships(System.Collections.Generic.IList entries) + 0x26 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges() + 0xc0 bytes 
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges() + 0x34 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(bool force) + 0x4e bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.HasChanges() + 0x2f bytes 
>       DataModels.dll!Armada.DataModels.Database.DatabaseHelpers.GetEntityState(System.Data.Entity.DbContext ctx, Object DataObject) Line 82 + 0x19 bytes  Basic
>       DataModels.dll!Armada.DataModels.Database.DatabaseHelpers.CheckModified(System.Data.Entity.DbContext ctx, Object DataObject) Line 65 + 0x1c bytes   Basic**

Code:

```
    Private Sub PaymentsViewModel_NewEntityRequest(ByRef Entity As PaymentViewModel) Handles Me.NewEntityRequest
        Dim pmt As Payment = DBCTX.DatabaseContext.Payments.Create
        With pmt
            .CompanyID = SelectedCompanyID
            .BorrowerID = Nothing
            .MortgageID = Nothing

            If SelectedBorrowerID.HasValue Then
                .Borrower = DBCTX.DatabaseContext.Borrowers.Find(SelectedBorrowerID.Value)
                .Mortgage = .Borrower.MortgageApplicants.FirstOrDefault.Mortgage ' get the first one loaded as the default
                .MortgageStatus = .Mortgage.MortgageStatus
            End If

            If SelectedDay.HasValue Then
                .PaymentDate = DateSerial(EffectiveDate.Value.Year, EffectiveDate.Value.Month, SelectedDay.Value)
            Else
                .PaymentDate = EffectiveDate.Value
            End If
            .PostingStatus = PaymentPostingStatuses.Unposted
            .PaymentType = PaymentTypes.Active
            .CreatedByUser = CurrentUser
            .DateCreated = Now
        End With

        DBCTX.DatabaseContext.Payments.Add(pmt)
        Entity = New PaymentViewModel(Me, pmt, True)
    End Sub
```

The code that checks for changes and triggers the 'nulling':
            Dim changes As IEnumerable(Of DbEntityEntry) = DBCTX.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(Function(ee) ee.State = EntityState.Added)

.
.
.
Dim cnt As Integer = MyBase.SaveChanges()

Comment: When it comes to navigation properties and FK columns I recommend using one or the other. Either a nav property and a shadow property for the FK, or just a FK column. For something like a CreatedBy user reference, I would generally opt for just a FK.  EF can have some odd behaviour when mapping both FKs and nav properties if you try setting FKs. (If there is a nav property then you should only set via nav and let the FK resolve)  Try removing the nav property for the CreatedByUser, or try setting the nav and not touching the FK. If no joy, put up some code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Everywhere else that I use this it works without problems.  One other interesting aspect is that if you add a single entity and check and then save it, it works.  Add 2 entities and the ChangeTracker erases the CreatedByUser.  I have tried creating the entity by setting it to either or both the key value and the entity - no difference.

Comment: With something like a CreatedByUser reference, it might be worth checking the DbContext configuration for any intercepts or such that might be trying to auto-populate or such.

Comment: The weird thing is that I set the ID value, then add it to the DBSet and EF automatically assigns the link to the CreatedByUser reference. If I stop and save it at that point, it works.  Adding the second entity for the same DBSet causes the Identity Tracker to reset the CreatedByUser reference and ID when I call it to check for changes. I am not sure what in the DBContext would be doing this?  LazyLoading is turned off - what else should I check there?

Comment: Can you reproduce the behaviour with a code example? What you describe does sound odd. If you set the ID and the reference is being set it is because the context is already tracking that entity. If you are setting a different ID on a different record and that one is not set, it would be because that entity isn't already tracked. However, if doing so removes the navigation property of the first association then something odd really would be going on. To piece that together would require seeing the code for the 2 entity updates.

Comment: Steve, please see code above.  It is running the same code above twice that causes everything to be 'nulled', e.g. Add one payment - good, add two - bad.

Comment: Thanks, that is a bit clearer now. Two things stand out.  What does this code do with the entity? `Entity = New PaymentViewModel(Me, pmt, True)` Are you storing a reference to the entity inside your view model, or simply copying values across. Why would the constructor for the view model take a reference to `Me`?   The second thing that stands out is that the DbContext.SaveChanges does not get called. I'm also curious how that context (DBCTX) is scoped/injected. (I.e. per request or transient)

Comment: Steve, everywhere else in my application that does this sort of thing, it works.  The constructor points to the Form View Model so that the Payment View Model can use it for services. The Database Context is supplied by a class that the Form View Model inherits from it stays live while the ViewModel is operating.  This class also detects the New event in the BindingSource, triggers the event so the descendant class can handle creating the new Entity.  When it returns it is still in the Add event and adds the new entity to the binding source. The Payment view model encapsulates the Payment.